# Keras binary classification: same prediction output class

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am using Keras sequential model for image classification. My problem is to find a particular watermark present in any part of the image or not. I am using a dataset of 9000 images. Keras backend is Tensorflow.

```
Keras==2.0.4  
tensorflow==1.2.1
```

While training, I am getting an accuracy of 86% and val_acc is 91%. But all the prediction result is categorizing to one category.

[image]

The program used for training is given below.

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
import cv2
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from PIL import ImageFile

ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True

classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape = (150, 150, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
classifier.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
classifier.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3))
classifier.add(Activation('relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 64, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.5))
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])


train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)
                                   #rotation_range=15,
                                   #zca_whitening=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('train',
                                                 target_size = (150, 150),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('test',
                                            target_size = (150, 150),
                                            batch_size = 32,
                                            class_mode = 'binary')

callbacks = [
  keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_loss', patience=10, verbose=0)
  ]

hist = classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         samples_per_epoch = 9000,
                         nb_epoch = 10,
                         validation_data = test_set,
                         nb_val_samples = 3000,
                         callbacks=callbacks)
                         # )
```

`train` directory has 2 subdirectories: `watermark` and `nonwatermark`. Am I doing anything wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It happen, when your network is shallow. You should try using pre-trained models or try to build deeper network. Your network is learning training data but not generalizing it.

Comment: @TusharGupta In the question, it is mentionned that Validation accuracy is 91%. I don't think this is a case of overfitting.

Comment: @Sunreef Yeah, I undertand, it's not overfitting. But in practical, I have observed that shallow network can behave weirdly. I agree with loannis Nasios answer as well.

Comment: @TusharGupta Will VGG19 code work?

Comment: @GayathriMenath Yeah you can use VGG19, InceptionV3 or resnet.

Comment: @TusharGupta Thanks. Let me check this

Comment: What does the confusion matrix look like?

Comment: @GayathriMenath did you solve this problem?

Comment: @GayathriMenath did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Are your classes unbalanced?
86% & 91 % accuracy seems high but if all the prediction result is categorizing to one category then probably one category is much bigger than the other.

There is no problem with that, you can have unbalanced categories but for you to know that your model is learning you need accuracy much higher than 91%.

I also agree with Gupta's comment above that your network is shallow and that using a **pretrained network** would help you enough.

#### EDIT

change

```
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
```

to

```
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 2, activation = 'softmax'))
```

and `loss = 'binary_crossentropy'` to `loss = 'categorical_crossentropy'`

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer

Comment: The classes are balanced and watermark dataset has created by manually watermarking the images on original image set.

Comment: 4500 images in each category

Comment: correct samples_per_epoch to np.ceil(9000/batch_size) and nb_val_samples to np.ceil(3000/batch_size)

Comment: The change suggested in the edit is irrelevant, they are both equivalent.